# What maven phase should I bind the flyway:migrate goal to?

Tags: maven, flyway

I'm using Flyway to keep my DB schema up to date. I'm hoping to automate this as a step in the build lifecyle using flyway's maven plugin which will execute the [`flyway:migrate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate) goal.

What maven phase should I bind this goal to? I'm confused because there's a few different use cases for this.

1. I want my **test db** completely destroyed and rebuilt every time tests are run, so it makes sense to execute the plugin once during the `test` phase
2. In my **development** environment I want my DB migrated (not rebuilt!) each time I build the project in general to keep the schema up to date. Would I bind this to... `package`? Or `compile`?
3. In my **production** environment I similarly want to run migrate again, but on my production DB. Should this even be automated, or should it be run manually? If it should be automated, would it be part of the `deploy` phase?

Thanks!

Comment: About your part 1. I would suggest to use the integration test phases like `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test` and `post-integration` cause these are integration tests than unit tests..and it does fit better into integration tests parts...Apart from that it sounds like you mistaken build time and run time....

Comment: Thanks, I realized i conflated build and run time after I posted the question. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would like to run the database migration during runtime, instead of during building your project with Maven.

To run the migration during runtime, please refer to the official documentation: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/api/. It provides several ways of configuring it:

### Programmatic Configuration

```java
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

...
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(url, user, password).load();
flyway.migrate();

// Start the rest of the application (incl. Hibernate)
...
```

### Spring Configuration

```xml
<bean id="flywayConfig" class="org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="..."/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <constructor-arg ref="flywayConfig"/>
</bean>

<!-- The rest of the application (incl. Hibernate) -->
<!-- Must be run after Flyway to ensure the database is compatible with the code -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="..." depends-on="flyway">
    ...
</bean>
```